# addClass only once onClick ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, css-animations, keyframe

Hi I'm new to ReactJS so I'm importing some work of mine to my project and turning it into components. I have a span acting as a button with keyframe animations, but when i load the page it gets animated.
One solution i have is to make a .class.animation and give the .animation class on the first click.
The thing is that I know how to code it in jquery but not on react.

The idea is to convert this into react:

```js
$('.navTrigger').onClick(function () {
    $(this).addClass('animations');
});
```

Right now I have this:

```js
const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
    
const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
};

return (
    <span onClick={handleToggle} className={`navTrigger ${isActive ? "" : "animations"} ${isActive ? "" : "active"}`}>
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
     </span>
);
```

I have a function where i toggle the active class to run backward and forward animations.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but I think that your boolean conditions are reversed for their purpose. If the buttton is active, you want it to be animated not the other way.

Comment: Just change this piece of code

const [isActive, setActive] = useState(true);

I hope you are looking to stop the auto animation on page load, so as per your logic set your isActive state to true

Comment: Srry the program i have right now is a toggle switch for the navTrigger.active the thing is that both '.navTrigger i' and '.active i' have animations so when i load the page the first animation occur. What im trying to do is separate the animations from the style (color, display, ...) and name it '.navTrigger.animations'. So now i want to add the animations class just once the first time i click the button

Answer (score 0):

What the code below does is on web load, the span starts with navTrigger class. The first time you click it its's given animations and active class. And then if you interact with it again it takes out active class and leaves animations there

```html
function MenuButton() {

    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);
 
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
        setAnimating(true);
    };


    return (
        <span onClick={handleToggle} className={`navTrigger ${animating ? "animations" : ""} ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
        </span>
    );
}
```